# Sql Select query Between 2 dates

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi I m using this Stored procedure to get some informations :

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[RevenusStaticAdvanced]
@Days int
as
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select ISNULL(SUM(CAST(TotalPrice as int)),0) as 'TotalPrice',
 ISNULL(COUNT(Lavage_Orders.ID),0) as 'Total Commandes'
from Lavage_Orders 
inner join LavageTypes on Lavage_Orders.LavageType=LavageTypes.ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(Day,Arrive,GETDATE()) Between 0 and @Days
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select ISNULL(COUNT(ID),0) as 'TotalCommandes' , ISNULL(SUM(CAST(TotalPrice as int)),0) as 'RevnusRepairs' 
from Repair_OrdersDetails 
WHERE DATEDIFF(Day,Date,GETDATE()) Between 0 and @Days
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select ISNULL(SUM(Qte),0) as 'SelledQte' , ISNULL(COUNT(ID),0) as 'TotalCommandes' , ISNULL(SUM(CAST(TotalPrice as int)),0) as 'RevnusAccessoires'
 from Accessoires_Order 
inner join Accessoires_OrderDetails on Accessoires_OrderDetails.orderID=Accessoires_Order.ID
WHERE DATEDIFF(Day,Date,GETDATE()) Between 0 and @Days
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select ISNULL(Accessoires.ID,0), ISNULL(SUM(Accessoires_OrderDetails.Qte),0) as Selled from Accessoires
inner join Accessoires_OrderDetails on Accessoires_OrderDetails.AccessoireID=ID
inner join Accessoires_Order on Accessoires_Order.ID=Accessoires_OrderDetails.orderID
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,Accessoires_Order.Date,GETDATE()) Between 0 and @Days
GROUP BY Accessoires.ID
ORDER BY Selled
DESC
```

this works perfectly when i give it a Number of days (from The curret Day ) 
So i want to change it To between 2 Dates so i changed the Condition to :

```
WHERE Date Between @Date1 and @Date2
```

but this doesnt seems to be working .

i pass the dates value in my c# like :

```
public AdvancedStatics AdvancedStaticsView2(DateTime D1,DateTime D2)
{
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        param[0].Value = D1;
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Date2", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        param[1].Value = D2;
}
```

The Stored Dates in My table like :

2017-01-11 14:20:48.177

Comment: " this doesnt seems to be working" is not a problem description, why doesn't it seem to be working? Be aware that `BETWEEN` is inclusive on both sides, and `datetime` without a time component will default to midnight. This means if `@Date1` = `21-03-2017` and `@Date2` = `23-03-2017`, the value `23-03-2017 14:20:48.177` won't be selected (it is larger than `23-03-2017 00:00:00.000`).

Comment: The fault is the c# code, didnt changed it to `@Days` parameter

Comment: @HoneyBadger So how can i change the between To take only Days in betweens

Comment: You can make the comparison casting `[Date]` to datatype `date`. By the way, if `[Date]` is the actual name of the column you want to compare, consider changing it's name, it's not a good idea to use keywords as object names.

Comment: I just tried and it still doesnt works , I Pass My date (Picked from a DateTimePicker ) as D1.ToShortDateString() and in my Query i changed it to Between Cast(@Date1 as Date) and cast(@Date2 as Date) since @Date1 is Varchar Type

Comment: You can do `WHERE CAST(Date AS date) Between CAST(@Date1 AS date) and CAST(@Date2 AS date)`. Keep all the dates in a date datatype. Further, if something doesn't work, please tell us **why** it doesn't work. Just a statement that "it doesn't work" tells me exactly nothing.

Comment: @HoneyBadger +1 on the `"it doesnt work" tells exactly nothing` statement. That is not descriptive

Comment: @Huster you should declare always in the stored procedure parameters with the same datatype of the value they store, that way you avoid possible casting errors and keep the SP code simple and less prone to errors. If they store `DateTime` they should not be declared in the SP as `NVarChar`

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters dont match the stored procedure parameters.

In case you want to pass a number of days:

```
public AdvancedStatics AdvancedStaticsView2(DateTime D1,DateTime D2)
{
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Days", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[0].Value = 45;
}
```

In case you want to pass two dates:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[RevenusStaticAdvanced]
(
    @Date1 DateTime,
    @Date2 DateTime,
)
as
```

Comment: BTW, at runtime, your c# code should raise an error complaining about missing parameters, it would have been wiser adding the error you got so people could help better.

Comment: By meaning i pass this value in my c# i meant on the seconde section not the first one

Comment: Don't understand your comment.

Comment: Edited to explain what I mean regarding "parameters mismatch"